# get 'for' value by javascript click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

my problem is when I want get 'for' value by javascript, the javascript return only last value :/
the php

```
if($this->test % 2 != 0)
{
        for ($z=$this->test+1;$z>=1;$z--) {
                 echo '<input type="submit" class="test" value="'.floor($z).'">';
}
```

the javascript:

```
$(".testi").click(function(){
        var t =  $(".testi").val();
        alert(t);
    });
```

why this javascript return only last value???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JavaScript is returning only the last value because your HTML contains multiple fields with the same class name. So, you must use `this` in the jQuery code to get the current element that you clicked:

```
$(".testi").click(function(){
    var t =  $(this).val();
    alert(t);
});
```

Comment: To OP @mokadem , please mark this answer or other as the answer for other people references. Until you mark the answer, this question still considered unsolved. This is not how SO works.

Answer (score -1):

php is a string processing language, its main purpose is to output some sort of string, so the result is a set of strings.

js doesn't return anything, its just a programm which runs and reacts on some events, so there is no concatenation of strings or return values by default

Every time a click happens the function will execute, get the current value from `.test1` and alert it.